# Best HTML5/Javascript Engine for Games 2D?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

Im searching for engines for Games 2D for using in Android/IOs devices.
Any idea? and why?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now using Impactjs. The engine is quite good. I think it is more available for development 2d platform game. (Something like Super mario style)

Also it have a own adapter for html5 canvas running on mobile. Actually that is a webbrowser which only for html5 canvas and disable all function. So the html5 canvas game can run on mobile very fast by the tool cal **[Ejecta](http://impactjs.com/ejecta)**

You can view there Web site **[here for Impactjs](http://impactjs.com/)**

Other then this one, I am also using [Libgdx](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/).
I recommand this one because it is using Java.

- Full Api document.
- Have Very good IDE to do the development.
- Full Api document.
- Many plugin support.  GUI for setting up project.
- Difference kind of 3rd part library support.

There is other game engine I have try. But I am not really like GUI control. (Using mouse clicking everywhere :D) So I give up them.
Such as **[Consturct](https://www.scirra.com/)**

I show you a list of Html5 game engine I have used here:

1. Cocos2D
2. ImpactJs
3. GameMakerStudio
4. EntityJS
5. Libgdx